# Как загружать на VPS файлы с помощью Rsync с помощью пользователя с пониженными привилегиями?

Tags: vps, rsync

Приведённая ниже команда работает нормально при запуске c Windows (разве что IP-адрес и имя папки скрыл):

```
rsync -azvr -e /bin/ssh --progress ./04-ProductionBuild/ root@160.XXX.XX.XX1:/var/www/example.com
```

На всякий случай скажу, что Rsync для Windows доступен, только его надо специально устанавливать (например с помощью пакетного менеджера `chocolatey`).

Однако как Вы знаете, отправлять данные с помощью учётной записи **root** небезопасно.
Но что будет, если отправить данные с помощью другой учётной записи?

```
rsync -azvr -e /bin/ssh --progress ./04-ProductionBuild/ non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XX1:/var/www/example.com
```

Такая вот ошибка:

```
rsync: change_dir#1 "/var/www/example.com" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(638) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

Хотя система доступа в UNIX-подобных операционных системах (одна из которых установлена на VPS) - настоящий кошмар для пользователей Windows,
пока в принципе всё объяснимо с токи зрения логики: видимо по умолчанию пользователь с пониженными привелениями не может ничего создавать, удалять, а иногда и вносить измененения.

Опять же, с точки зрения логики эти права надо дать, но отсюда возникает много вопросов:

1. Какие *минимальные* права надо дать пользователю, который загружает данные через Rsync?
2. Если дать права на запись, изменение и удаление файлов из дректории "var/www/example.com", эти права будут распространяться на всё файлы, что в этой директории? Что-то мне подсказывает, что нет.

Нагугленное решение добавить нижеследующую строку

```
non_root_admin ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

ничего не дало.

Comment: 1. Права на чтение и запись нужного каталога и всех его вложенных в него файлов и каталогов; 2. Нет, нужно явно выдать права везде где надо (если каталог изначально не пустой)

Comment: Однако лично у меня с rsync вылезала проблема: он пытается обновить права и время изменения целевого каталога, а это означает, что также нужны права на изменение **родительского** каталога — то есть `/var/www` в данном примере. Наверно, можно как-то это обойти, поигравшись с опциями типа `--omit-dir-times`, но я в этом как-то не особо преуспел

Comment: @andreymal, Благодарю Вас за комментарий, но всё-таки объявлю конкурс в надежде на подробную лекцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробные лекции? их есть у меня! xD

Есть несколько способов разрешить пользователям с непривилегированными учетными записями изменять файлы в определенных директориях на Unix-подобных системах. Вот несколько из них:

1. **Измените владельца директории**: Вы можете использовать команду `chown` для изменения владельца директории на `non_root_admin`. Это позволит `non_root_admin` делать всё, что он захочет, с файлами в этой директории. Команда будет выглядеть примерно так: `chown -R non_root_admin /var/www/example.com`.
2. **Измените группу директории**: Если `non_root_admin` является членом определенной группы, вы можете сделать эту группу владельцем директории. Затем вы можете установить разрешения так, чтобы члены этой группы могли изменять файлы. Команды будут выглядеть примерно так: `chgrp -R groupname /var/www/example.com` и `chmod -R g+w /var/www/example.com`.
3. **Используйте ACLs (Access Control Lists)**: ACLs предоставляют более гибкий способ управления правами доступа к файлам, чем стандартная система разрешений Unix. Вы можете установить ACL так, чтобы `non_root_admin` мог изменять файлы в определенной директории, используя команду `setfacl`. Сначала вам может потребоваться установить пакет `acl` на вашем сервере.

Обратите внимание, что все эти команды должны быть выполнены с привилегиями `root`.

Относительно строки `non_root_admin ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` в sudoers файле - это позволяет `non_root_admin` запускать `rsync` с правами `root` без ввода пароля. Однако, это не меняет разрешений на директории или файлы, которые `rsync` пытается изменить. `rsync` по-прежнему не сможет записать файлы в директорию, если у `non_root_admin` нет соответствующих разрешений на эту директорию.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за отличную лекцию!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте опцию acl к монтированию диска (/etc/fstab).

Через команду `setfacl` установите разрешения на запись.

На моём сайте получилось как-то так:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/www/html/example.com/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:siter:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:group:siter:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Можно обойтись без acl. Установить в папке группу  www-data на все и дать rw к файлам и rwx к папкам на эту группу. добавить пользователя в группу www-data. После загрузки файлов менять группу на www-data ещё раз, чтоб вэбсервер не потерял доступ к файлам.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Вас ответ.